# DateTime Selectlist from model to view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, code-first

I am working on a personal endeavor to make my first game using MVC and EF.

I have this class called Race.
This has a DateTime field which is going to hold the time at which the race will be "automated" by the server.

Now when a user creates this race. They have to pick a DateTime here.
The date times shown in the list are added in the Race Model.
Where i have a list of times that get converted into a date based on today and the following 2 days.

The problem i am having is.
Using the clean approach. (my selectlists are null)
Using the dirty approach (my model can't save because the DateTime field is a string instead of a DateTime field)

/* Race Class */

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DOCCL.Models
{
    public class Race
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Purse is required")]
        public int Purse { get; set; }
        public int? Slots { get; set; }
        public int SlotPrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RaceTime { get; set; }

        public int? TrackId { get; set; }
        public virtual Track Track { get; set; }

        public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
        public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Horse> RacingHorses { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RaceResult> RaceResults { get; set; }

        public Race()
        {
            SlotPrice = 0; //default value
            Slots = 8;


        }

        public SelectList SlotOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return new SelectList(AllSlotOptions, "Index", "Slot", Slots);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<SlotOption> AllSlotOptions
        {
            get
            {
                int[] slotOptions = { 8, 12, 16 };
                int index = 1;
                foreach (int slotOption in slotOptions)
                {
                    yield return new SlotOption
                    {
                        Index = index,
                        Slot = slotOption,
                    };
                    ++index;
                }
            }
        }

        public class SlotOption
        {
            public int Index { get; set; }
            public int Slot { get; set; }
        }

        public SelectList TimeSlotOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return new SelectList(AllTimeSlotOptions, "Index", "Slot", RaceTime);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TimeSlotOption> AllTimeSlotOptions
        {
            get
            {
                int[] slotOptions = { 9, 12, 15, 18, 21 };

                int index = 1;
                for (int day = 0; day <= 2; day++)
                {
                    foreach (int slotOption in slotOptions)
                    {
                        DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + day, slotOption, 0, 0);

                        if (dt > DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            yield return new TimeSlotOption
                            {
                                Index = index,
                                Slot = dt
                            };
                        }
                        ++index;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class TimeSlotOption
        {
            public int Index { get; set; }
            public DateTime Slot { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

/* RaceController */

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]

    public ActionResult Create(Race race)
    {
        User user = entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name));
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user.Finances -= 500;
            entities.Races.Add(race);
            entities.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(race);
    }
```

/* Race\Create */

```
@model DOCCL.Models.Race

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_frontend.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


<div class="ten columns alpha omega">
    <h2>Create race</h2>
</div>

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
            <div class="ten columns alpha omega">
                <div class="three columns alpha">@Html.LabelFor(race => race.Name)</div>
                <div class="three columns">@Html.TextBoxFor(race => race.Name)</div>
                <div class="four columns omega">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(race => race.Name)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ten columns alpha omega">
                <div class="three columns alpha">@Html.LabelFor(race => race.RaceTime)</div>
                <div class="three columns">@Html.DropDownList("RaceTime", DOCCL.Models.Race.AllTimeSlotOptions.Select(ts => new SelectListItem {Value = ts.Slot.ToString(), Text = ts.Slot.ToString() }) , "-- Race --")</div>
                <div class="four columns omega">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(race => race.RaceTime)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ten columns alpha omega">
                <div class="three columns alpha">@Html.LabelFor(race => race.Slots)</div>
                <div class="three columns">@Html.DropDownList("Slots", DOCCL.Models.Race.AllSlotOptions.Select(ts => new SelectListItem {Value = ts.Index.ToString(), Text = ts.Slot.ToString() }) , "-- Slots --")</div>
                <div class="four columns omega">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(race => race.Slots)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ten columns alpha omega">
                <div class="three columns alpha">@Html.LabelFor(race => race.SlotPrice)</div>
                <div class="three columns">@Html.TextBoxFor(race => race.SlotPrice)</div>
                <div class="four columns omega">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(race => race.SlotPrice)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ten columns alpha omega">
                <div class="offset-by-eight two columns alpha omega">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Create" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

/* Clean attempt */

```
<div class="ten columns alpha omega">
    <div class="three columns alpha">@Html.LabelFor(race => race.RaceTime)</div>
    <div class="three columns">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RaceTime, Model.TimeSlotOptions, "-- Race time --")</div>
    <div class="four columns omega">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(race => race.RaceTime)</div>
</div>
<div class="ten columns alpha omega">
    <div class="three columns alpha">@Html.LabelFor(race => race.Slots)</div>
    <div class="three columns">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Slots, Model.SlotOptions, "-- Slot --")</div>
    <div class="four columns omega">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(race => race.Slots)</div>
</div>
```

So obviously the last one is the nicest and it returns null because i don't actually have a Race object yet. and thus i can't reach the selectlist.

Does any of you know how to do this properly?

Comment: Still looking for some sort of insight into this. If anyone has any way of doing this i'd be more than happy to re-factor if necessary. Looking to learn in the process of making this game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the 2 lists into a common helper class.
And instantiate them from there.

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RaceTime, new SelectList(Model.TimeSlotOptions, "Id", "Name"), "-- Race time --")
```

instead of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RaceTime, Model.TimeSlotOptions, "-- Race time --")
```

Comment: Gave that a go. same issue. null reference exception.